Why Brucker mq-NF NMR use a steady gradient when measuring Diffusion Coeffient?
Brucker mq-Series NMR uses PGSE/PGSTE to measure the diffusion coefficient of water and oil. However, in their user manual (UIC, 4.2.1),  a so-called "steady gradient" which makes the B0 homogeneity worse was involved. Theoretically, B0 should be as homogeneous as possible to get an accurate D.  But the user manual tells:

During measurements a steady field gradient is applied to guarantee a
defined magnetic field homogeneity of 0.5 ms. This homogeneity value
provides stable gradient echoes [why???], but does not disturb [in my machine, the steady gradient is larger than 12%, this is a large background gradient and could not be ignored] this kind of
measurements at all.

Brucker is a big giant in NMR. They should not make this kind of mistake. My question is: why the steady gradient is needed and how it help the experiment?


"a so-called "steady gradient" which makes the B0 homogeneity worse was involved."
No. The gradient is in contrary intended to make the homogeneity better!
The gradient is calibrated to optimize the homogeneity, as the manual says:
"This calibration step adjusts the steady gradient in order to obtain a signal width (homogeneity) of 0.5 ms"

At the same time, I am also curious about why Bruker defines homogeneity in terms of time; this 0.5ms seems to be the time for the FID signal to decay completely. However, if that's the case, the better the homogeneity, the longer this decay time should be. But in my case, when the gradient is turned on, the decay time is reduced, and it is longer when the gradient is not turned on.

First, I am no tomograhy expert, I know high-res NMR well, but not tomography.
My guess is that what perhaps is intended here is to reach "a [b]defined[/b] magnetic field homogeneity", not the best possible homogeneity. And Bruker defines this as about 0,5 s decay time of the FID.
Normally the longer the FID, the better the homogeneity. So one can roughly define homogeneity via length/time.

Now it's even more peculiar. In theory, the better the homogeneity of B0, the more accurate the measured diffusion coefficient. Why does Bruker require a B0 with poorer homogeneity for measurement? What benefits could such a defined magnetic field homogeneitty bring?
